Why is google app script running outside of coded permitted times?
Below, the script specifically only permits Mon-Fri running of the code. But tt can be seen in the version history, it's been running on Saturday and Sunday and indeed updates the data inside the sheet on Saturday and Sunday.
function copyDataToHistorical() {
  // Check if today is a weekday (Monday to Friday)
  var today = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek = today.getDay(); // 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, ..., 6 is Saturday

  // Check if it's a weekday (Monday to Friday)
  if (dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek <= 5) {
    // Get the active spreadsheet and sheets
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var todaySheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("TodaysData");
    var historicalSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("HistoricalData");

    // Get the data range from TodaysData
    var dataRange = todaySheet.getRange("A4:O16");

    // Get the values from the range
    var values = dataRange.getValues();

    // Find the last unused row in HistoricalData
    var lastRow = historicalSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = historicalSheet.getLastColumn();
    var lastRowValues = historicalSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues()[0];

    // Check if the last row is empty
    var isEmpty = lastRowValues.every(function(value) {
      return value === '';
    });

    // If the last row is not empty, find the next empty row
    if (!isEmpty) {
      lastRow = historicalSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    }

    // Copy the values to HistoricalData
    historicalSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, values. Length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Today is not a weekday.");
  }
}


In your situation, how is the function copyDataToHistorical() executed?

It's called by an app trigger.
Time-driven
Day timer
5pm to 6pm
I understand now the trigger is called every day (i.e. it's not just called weekdays).  Why does the script run after the day of week filter line?

I just added 5 weekly timers, choosing Mon, Tues, etc. I noticed that the function name is different for the original trigger (that script I deleted, darn it) so I'm concluding that the day of week filter wasn't in the earlier version of the script. Do you perhaps have an alternate explanation? Thank you for the question, by the way.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed another approach as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

As another approach, how about using a Google Apps Script library? I thought that the script for managing the time-driven trigger might be a bit difficult. So, I have created a Google Apps Script library for managing the time-driven triggers. Ref
Usage:
1. Install Google Apps Script library
You can see how to install TriggerApp at here.
2. Sample script
From your question, if you want to run the function copyDataToHistorical, at 17:00 every "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", and "Friday", the sample script is as follows. In this case, your function copyDataToHistorical is not required to be modified.
function sample(e) {
  const obj = [
    {
      ownFunctionName: "sample",
      functionName: "copyDataToHistorical",
      everyWeek: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"],
      atTimes: ["17:00:00"],
    },
  ];
  const res = TriggerApp.setEventObject(e).installTriggers(obj, console.log);
  console.log(res);
}

3. Run
In this case, please run the above function sample. By this, the next trigger is installed. The flow of this script is as follows.

When sample is run at "2024-04-17 00:00:00", the trigger is installed to "2024-04-17 17:00:00". <--- Wednesday
When sample is run at "2024-04-17 17:00:00", the trigger is installed to "2024-04-18 17:00:00". <--- Thursday
When sample is run at "2024-04-18 17:00:00", the trigger is installed to "2024-04-19 17:00:00". <--- Friday
When sample is run at "2024-04-19 17:00:00", the trigger is installed to "2024-04-22 17:00:00". <--- Monday
When sample is run at "2024-04-22 17:00:00", the trigger is installed to "2024-04-23 17:00:00". <--- Tuesday

This cycle continues to be run.
Note:

In this script, 2 triggers are used. From I just added 5 weekly timers, choosing Mon, Tues, etc., I thought that this method might be able to reduce the number of triggers.

Reference:

TriggerApp (Author: me)

